# Is it possible to have a point light cast shadows but no reflection?

Tags: unity

I'm working in Unity 5.3.6.  I have a point light that is simulating sunlight from a window.  It looks great, except the floor reflects a bright white circle.  I want the floor to reflect other lights in the room, just not this one.  Is this possible?